# List all scalar Function with datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to executable query which is return all scalar function with datatype in Database.Thru the below query we can get the scalar function

`select * from sys.objects where type = 'FN'`

but i want to return only those function which has return datatype is 'Nvarchar'

Comment: [`sys.parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx): "If the object is a scalar function, **parameter_id** = 0 represents the return value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT
    so.name,
    sp.parameter_id,
    sp.name,
    sp.user_type_id
FROM sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.parameters sp
    ON sp.object_id = so.object_id
WHERE so.type = 'FN'
AND sp.parameter_id = 0
AND sp.user_type_id = 231
```

Comment: i am use  `sp.system_type_id  = 231`, it will include user define datatypes which is use `Nvarchar`